# Bring the current Activity in foreground when a call is starting from app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bluetooth

I have a App where I can start a call. When the call is running, I have to go back to my app more specifically to my Activity. My idea was to bring the current Activity in foreground.

**Now I have this solution:**

```
Intent it = new Intent();
it.setComponent(new ComponentName(CheckVehicleActivity.this.getPackageName(),  CheckVehicleActivity.class.getName()));
it.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
CheckVehicleActivity.this.getApplicationContext().startActivity(it);
```

This is already working. 
**But:** I have a Bluetooth Connection too and when I do it this way, the communication doesn't work anymore. I don't know why this is happening. Then I have to cancel and start my Bluetooth connection again. But this causes other problems in the hole process of the usage of the app.

**So my question is:**
Is there a way to bring the app in foreground when the call is running, **without** using an Intent. Or does anyone know an other solution to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bring another activity into the foreground without intent as this goes against the entire Activity approach that android utilizes.

Comment: Ok. Do you know another solution to run the call in background?

Comment: Other question: If I use a service for calling, do I still see the Android Call GUI?

Comment: A service does not have any form of GUI. Also please specify what you mean by "Android Call GUI" ?

Comment: yes but it will start the call. And I want to know if then the Dialer of the Android call appears?

Comment: If you launch an intent from your service then it should work.